# How to identify given dataset is already feature scaled?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

I have just started machine learning, and I am curious about it. We often do feature scaling for more faster convergence with respect to Gradient Descent.
But is there any technique, so that i can beforehandedly find whether dataset is feature scaled without looking into it.

Comment: I'm really curious to know what you mean by "without looking into it"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking into it might be difficult... What do you mean by not looking?

If you are going to look into it, you can check if the individual features already have zero mean and unit variance.

Comment: I meant, we should not be checking individual features for it's scaled features. I should be able to write function to do this check without me checking with data points for each feature.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible, when scaling features each feature is scaled individually so any check you make must be done on feature basis. In addition, to check if a given feature is scaled you need to know about its mean and variance, perhaps this can be done by sampling the feature and not calculating the mean and variance over all datapoint, but still you need to look into the data.

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to Cross Validated. If this answer was of any help, please consider marking it as accepted.